# Using Flip Fluids for a shore on a beach. Doesn't behave like ocean water

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have assigned the appropriate materials and enabled Whitewater simulation. The water still looks and behaves like oil.

I know I am doing something wrong. Can someone please explain?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a commercial third-party addon, not part of Blender and questions about it are off-topic here. You'll have to ask about it on their web site.

Comment: pls provide a blend file, thx